# unable to connect through website using localhost or IP address

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I am trying to connect to a website which is hosted locally on a server but unable to connect. I have reset the IIS and try to connect it using local host but its is not working. I haven't change any thing and able to connect through it yesterday.
Can some please help and tell me what to do and what are the possibilities that why I am not able to connect.

Comment: Have you tried pinging the server IP address?  Does a ping go through?

Comment: What http error code do you get? Have you changed any code since it was working?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check three things.

1. If you are using a local host name check that, the same bindning is set on your site and that the same host name row exists in your hosts file (usually in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts) like this example:

   ```
   127.0.0.1    localsite.dev
   ```
2. Check that the sites root is pointing to the correct directory on your local machine.
3. If you have access to a local development tool, like Visual studio, try to compile and see if build errors exists.